# Android: using requestSingleUpdate or replace it

Tags: android, geolocation

i'm working on app, which must get latitude and longitude. in my case `requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` is not in option. why? because i must get location just when user do something that location is needed (let's say he hits button). and i need location exactly on the time, when button is hit. in `requestLocationUpdates`, we can set minTime-if i set this let's say on 30000 the location at the "button hit time" won't be as good as i want. of the same reason minDistance is also not as good as i want. if i understant function `requestLocationUpdates` correct-when minTime and minDistance are set to 0, location is updating all the time. please correct me if i'm wrong. app is for company that i'm working at and that app will be used through the day and night. so if app will check for location updates all the time, battery would be often empty. thst's why i need location just at the time, that button is hit. i found [requestSingleUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) function. but i can't use it in eclipse =( like it doesn't exists.
is there some other way to do this or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) method, but it can be out-of-date. requestLocationUpdates is asynchronous because gps needs to "warm-up" to find new location. 
requestSingleUpdate method is available since api level 9, but you can implements it's using requestLocationUpdates and disabling updates after first callback to LocationListener.

Comment: i can't use getLastKnownLocation of 2 reasons: 1. it can be out-of-date as you said. 
2. not all devices will have allowed gps (i must use network provider). so when device rebots, location will be null when i call getLastKnownLocation. 
how can i disable update?

Comment: this technique is explained here http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Answer (score 2):

The [requestSingleLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) method new for API level 9.  If you are targeting an earlier API level, this method will not be available to you.

One of the problems with obtaining location information is that it can take time to get a fix.  This is more of a problem with the GPS location provider than the network provider.  If you are only using the network provider, then there may not much of a delay with getting the location information when the user clicks the button (I say this knowing nothing about what your app does with the data, or what type of user experience you are trying to provide).

Something else you can try is the [PASSIVE_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER).  It allows you to get location updates that were requested from other apps.  This will mean that you have to request the [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](http://android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) permission however.  You may also need to leave something running to receive the location updates (likely a service or a [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)).  The BroadcastReceiver approach should not use that much additional battery life since it only runs when the Intent is received along with the PASSIVE_PROVIDER only getting locations when some other app requested them anyways.

The other sticky point with the PASSIVE_PROVIDER is that you should eventually call [removeUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).  Where and when to call this really depends on how your app is structured and how you handle the user exiting the app.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, PASSIVER_PROVIDER requires API level 8.