# I get an error on calling Locations Manager requestSingleUpdate

Tags: android, request, location

I am implementing the code from "A deep dive into location" and the last line at the following code produces an error:

```
if (locationListener != null && (bestTime < minTime || bestAccuracy > minDistance)) { 
  IntentFilter locIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(SINGLE_LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION);
  context.registerReceiver(singleUpdateReceiver, locIntentFilter);      
  locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, singleUpatePI);
```

It seems that requestSingleUpdate is not defined for LocationManager although it is in the sample code and I have seen people saying they've implemented this code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer on a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5469101/1285338

This API exists from API level 9 and on